# how to split at ALL special characters with re.split()

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split at any special character using `re.split()` from the `import re` package. This is what I have done so far, but doesn't really seem to work out yet. Any ideas?

```
word = [b for b in re.split(r'\`\-\=\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\[\]\{\}\;\'\\\:\"\|\<\,\.\/\>\<\>\?', a)]
```

Comment: Could you describe your specific problem please? What exactly is wrong, what's supposed to happen with sample inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: What's a "special" character? And by inference: what's a "regular" one (as opposed to special)? Non-alphabetic? Non-alphanumeric? In which locale/language?

Comment: Define *special character* and `a`.

Comment: Have you tried something like `re.split(r"[^\w\d\s]", s)`? (Problem: `_` is in `\w`) Also, why the list comprehension?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a character class:

```
re.split(r'[`\-=~!@#$%^&*()_+\[\]{};\'\\:"|<,./<>?]', a)
```

Answer (score 20):

Instead of enumerating all the "special" characters, it might be easier to create a class of characters where *not* to split and to reverse it using the `^` character.

For example, `re.split(r"[^\w\s]", s)` will split at any character that's *not* in either the class `\w` or `\s` (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` respectively, see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more info). However, note that the `_` character is included in the `\w` class, so you might instead want to explicitly specify all the "regular" characters, e.g. `re.split(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", s)`.

```
>>> re.split(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", "foo bar_blub23/x~y'z")
['foo bar', 'blub23', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: I like this one because it uses the built-in character classes effectively.

Comment: What if you want to split across space as well?. For example in the given sample, I want to split foo and bar into two strings based on the space between them as a delimiter, then what changes do I need to make to the given regular expression.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to split the string when you meet a character which isn't alphanumeric. For that, you can use the metacharacter `\w` in regex which means "every letter a-ZA-Z0-9" and match the opposite with `^` like this:

```
>>> re.split(r'[^\w]', 'toto"t"o/t!')
['toto', 't', 'o', 't', '']
```